# only if VS even if

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

Would you please throw a light into whether or not there is any difference between the following?

only if

even if

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Were you trying to use them in a specific context?

**Only if** and **even if** are used similarly.

**Only if** means there's one specific thing that has to happen. If that **one** condition is not met, then there is no hope.

> You can remarry only if you get a divorce first.
>
> You can win the lottery only if you bought a ticket.

**Even if** means despite. It usually introduces some negative things that make the event less likely, but not impossible.

> I will love you forever even if you grow old and ugly.
>
> You might win the lottery even if you only bought one ticket.

Answer (score 1):

> Only if

Used to present limiting conditions:
*I will go to the store **only if** it stops raining.*

If it stops raining, I am going to the store.  If it keeps raining, I am staying home.

> Even if

Used to present conditions which will *not* be limiting conditions: *I will go to the store **even if** it is still raining.*

It doesn't matter whether it is raining or not raining.  I am going to the store.